# PHPExcel Pie Chart Series Options 25% on primary axis

Tags: php, phpexcel, pie-chart

I was able to create 2 pie charts programmatically (im using PHP), using the PHPExcel library (no need to list the code since it's too large) but i can not find a way to increase the distance between the pie's pieces like in the picture below. Basically, im trying to programmatically increase the Series Options on primary axis by 25%.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you init new **PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries** object, you can specified **$plotStyle=true**.

```
public function __construct($plotType = null, $plotGrouping = null, $plotOrder = array(), $plotLabel = array(), $plotCategory = array(), $plotValues = array(), $plotDirection = null, $smoothLine = null, $plotStyle = null)
```

For PHPExcel\Examples\33chartcreate-pie.php:88 it will be something like there:

```
$series1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_PIECHART,
    NULL,                                                   
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues1)-1),                  
    $dataSeriesLabels1,                                     
    $xAxisTickValues1,                                      
    $dataSeriesValues1,                                     
    null,
    null,
    true
);
```

In sources:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Chart.php#L1169

Answer (score 0):

If the two pie charts are always the same, you can create them on an empty Excel Workbook, increase the distance, save it in a place where your script can reach it and use this workbook as a template with PHPExcel : open the workbook in your script and instead of creating the pie charts just update their formulas.

Comment: No, the pie charts are not always the same: they vary based on some GUI criteria that creates the table above the 2 pie charts from where the pie charts get their values from...